# JQuery - Combining width and hide effects

Tags: jquery, show-hide

Complete beginner so I'm probably missing something obvious but...
I can't seem to combine an animate(width) effect with a this.hide effect, I can make either one work by commenting out the other. Here's the code:

```
function showSlidingDiv(column){
var maxWidth = 200;
var smallWidth = 80;
var myWidth = $(column).width();


$("div").each(function(){
        $(this).animate({width: smallWidth});
        $(this).hide();
     });

$(column).show();
$(column).animate({width: maxWidth});
}
```

I'm using this on a large table of information so that the user can click on a th heading and expand that column of information while reducing all the others. Each td has a div inside it that is being expanded or contracted. I would like to also hide, if possible by animation, the divs in the other columns at the same time. Like I said, this will work for one or the other, but not both together.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) isn't a queued function, you either need to call it in a [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) callback, like this:

```
$("div").animate({width: smallWidth}, function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Or make it a queued function with this trick:

```
$("div").animate({width: smallWidth}).hide(0);
```

There's no need for the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) in either case, since the above code will apply to all matches as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just use callback functions. Like:

```
function showSlidingDiv(column) {
  var maxWidth = 200;
  var smallWidth = 80;
  var myWidth = $(column).width();


  $("div").each(function() {
    $(this).animate({width: smallWidth}, 1000, function() {
      // this callback is executed when the animation is done
      $(this).hide();
    });
  });

  $(column).show();
  $(column).animate({width: maxWidth});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery animate function can be used with a callback function that runs once the animation is completed, this should accomplish what you're trying to do.

```
$("div").each(function(){
    $(this).animate({width: smallWidth}, 1000, function() {
       $(this).hide();
    });
 });
```

Comment: You don't need a duration here, it works without...but to keep the default duration, it's 400ms, this would take much longer :)

Comment: Actually, just one small bug. Everything works, but when I click a heading to expand it, all divs appear for the duration of the animation, then hide once complete. For some reason everything flashes on then goes to the correct state. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that only animation methods are chained (one after the other). To make `hide()` an animation method you must specify a duration, so instead of

```
    $(this).animate({width: smallWidth});
    $(this).hide();
```

write

```
    $(this).animate({width: smallWidth});
    $(this).hide(0);
```

or shorter

```
    $(this).animate({width: smallWidth}).hide(0);
```